# Why the signal disappears when setting refresh rate to 120Hz?

Tags: windows-7, 3d-vision, 120hz

Configuration:
Monitor - Samsung RZ2233
GPU - nVidia GeForce 9800GTX
nVidia GeForce 3D Vision glasses
OS: Win7 x64
new drivers installed today

The monitor itself is working fine at 1600×1050@60Hz. Whenever the refresh rate is set to 120Hz for 3D vision to work the screen goes black and monitor displays a no signal/check cable message. At first I thought that the single-link DVI cable is insufficient for that, but even at 640×480 with 256 colours it does not work so it should not be the case. The same happens when running the setup wizard or anything that sets the refresh rate above 60Hz.
How can I find the source of it an how to remove it?

Solution: Dual link DVI cable helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, that the monitor is recognized by windows. Maybe it is installed as a generic TFT and windows is prohibiting the refresh rate to avoid damage to the monitor.

Furthermore, if you want to see HDCP content this is only possible in Single-Link-Mode at 60Hz.

Make sure you have a Dual Link DVI Cable. It should be written on the cable if you have one.

Comment: I was about to comment and point out that this is a 120Hz monitor but apparently you figured that out.

Comment: @Shinrai Make sure you have a Dual Link DVI cable.

Comment: @Darokthar - Who, me?  Not my question, hehe <3

Comment: Thanks for answer. The settings actually change to 120Hz, and than back after 15s of not confirming the change. Currently I have only single link cable - is double link needed even for very low resolutions?

Comment: @Lukas - I think you're right about the single-link being sufficient, honestly.  I am unsure though.

Comment: @Lukas Sorry it is not sufficient. Read this wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface

Comment: @Darokthar - Wikipedia doesn't say anything specific.  4Gbps isn't sufficient for 640x480 at 120Hz? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Dual link DVI cable helped. Aparently bitrate is not the only important thing...